# Is it possible to see the data of push notification from APNS on iPhone?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am currently debugging for an existing iOS application, and I need to use the data from push notification to perform some actions. Since the backend team failed to provide me with the data model of their push notification, I have to figure it out myself.

The push is only available on TestFlight build (which means I couldn't print the push notification in my Xcode). Therefore I tried to setup a proxy using `mitmproxy` to intercept it. But somehow the push notification is not shown in the `mitmproxy` terminal.

I did some basic research and it seems to me it is impossible to intercept and see the push notification from apns on my macbook. Can someone give me a hint of where to look for and start with?

Comment: you can try using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application and present a custom VC to display the dict received